# Oracle - split the string by comma and get the last sub-str

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I wanted to write an Oracle query to extract only the last sub-string of comma separated string like below:

```
DEST = "1,MMA SALAI,ARIANKUPAM,CITY CENTRE,G12 47H"
```

I am interested in only G12. How do I get in the Oracle query?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Just a hint, try a combo of substr and instr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,MMA SALAI,ARIANKUPAM,CITY CENTRE,G12 47H', '[^,]+$')
```

But that will fetch `G12 47H`. You may consider

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,MMA SALAI,ARIANKUPAM,CITY CENTRE,G12 47H', '([^, ]+)( +[^,]*)?$', 1,1,NULL,1)
```

This will give `G12`.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of *substringing* (see comments within the code):

```
SQL> with test (dest) as
  2    (select '1,MMA SALAI,ARIANKUPAM,CITY CENTRE,G12 47H' from dual)
  3  select
  4    regexp_substr(dest,              --> out of the DEST, give me ...
  5                  '\w+',             --> ... the first word that begins right after ...
  6                  instr(dest, ',', 1, regexp_count(dest, ',')) + 1     --> ... postition of the last
  7                 ) result                                              --> comma in the source string
  8  from test;

RESULT
--------------------
G12

SQL>
```

---

Or, by splitting the comma-separated values into rows:

```
SQL> with test (dest) as
  2    (select '1,MMA SALAI,ARIANKUPAM,CITY CENTRE,G12 47H' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+') result
  4  from (select regexp_substr(dest, '[^,]+', 1, level) col,  --> split column to rows
  5               row_number() over (order by level desc) rn   --> the last row will be RN = 1
  6        from test
  7        connect by level <= regexp_count(dest, ',') + 1
  8       )
  9  where rn = 1;

RESULT
--------------------
G12

SQL>
```